# SASS partial overlay depending on brand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I have an app that supports multiple brands, each having their own color scheme, logo, etc..

The base SASS files are the same, but I have several `/brands/_brand.sass`. Assuming I have a way of detecting which brand is loaded, is there a way to load the specific sass file on top of the main stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite that you have the same css/sass files, probably in future you'll have to set specific settings for every brand, so i'd prefer to create layout for every brand and simply use it controller:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  layout @brand # @brand = 'apple', 'ibm', ...
  #...
end
```

But if you still want to have one layout, it's simple:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag @brand %> # @brand = 'apple', 'ibm', ...
```

where sass files will be apple.sass, ibm.sass, ... and @brand is variable in your controller.